# Foreign Key referencing PK vs Foreign Key referencing a unique key

Tags: sql

What is considered as a better/standard approach:

1. A foreign key referencing the primary key of another table (the PK is auto-increment numeric values).
2. A foreign key referencing the unique key of another table (the unique key column holds meaningful data rather than auto-generated values).

Is there any performance benefits of one approach over the other?

Ideally speaking, the unique key column should have been the PK too, but that is something that I cannot change.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'd say this is a subjective question, as it will depend on things like indexes in your server and your dbms. for example, foreign key constraints are not automatically indexed by SQL Server. Also, if your programmers use an ORM, they may have an easier time with FKs that reference a real PK

Comment: A FK *typically* references the PK of the referenced table - but there's no downside or drawback of any kind in referencing a unique index on the referenced table instead. No difference in performance, either

Comment: The DBMS is Oracle, but my question is generic, that is the reason I tagged the question only with SQL.

Comment: @Mubin the DBMS question was leading to an answer like Nikki9696 gave in her comment; that is the real answer.  If you have an index on your unique key, it should perform the same as joining to a primary key with an index on it by default.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of using a unique key as a primary key, especially if you have to store the unique key data for other purposes anyway. It's sad that's something you cannot change, so I'm not sure where you're going with this question. But the only performance issues that come to mind would be the size of the keys, as some datatypes obviously use more storage than other datatypes which would eventually affect query performance. Either way should enforce referential integrity and prevent orphaned records.